# Is there a portable way of defining replaceable function/variable/constant?

Tags: c++, c, portability

By replaceable function I mean something like the `new` and `delete` operators in C++ which are replaced if a user-provided definition is supplied.

Is there a reasonably portable way of achieving this in a library for other cases than operator `new` and `delete` (in C/C++)? Or would one need to solve this separately for each implementation?

For a concrete example let's assume that the library contains:

```
int the_answer(void) {
    return 42;
}
```

and then a program using that would want to override this:

```
int the_answer(void) {
    return 43;
}

int main() {
    printf("The answer is %d\n", the_answer());
}
```

it should result in it printing "The answer is 43" (but if commenting out the last definition of `the_answer` it would write "The answer is 42").

The actual use case is to be able to customize the behavior of the library by overriding data for default behavior.

Comment: do you want to add a new `operator` to the language?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to ask.  can you demonstrate what you would like to replace?

Comment: @NathanOliver I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: In C++ you'd do this through inheritance.

Comment: it's still uncler what you're asking

Comment: @DavidHaim What is it that you think is unclear?

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can use the fact that a template has a lower priority than an implementation that does not require implicit casts/construction of arguments.

```
// library function
template <class = void>
int the_answer() { return 42; }

// optional override
int the_answer() { return 43; }
```

Note that the definition order is not important, the template always loses.

Comment: The problem here is that the one that's declared at the point of the call that wins. After compilation it's cut in stone which one that has won and that's the one that has to be overridden.

Comment: If you want to override at runtime you have to use function pointers or virtual functions and pay for the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, for anything except operators. Note that C does not have operator overloading, so your question is mis-tagged.

For functions/variables/constants, you could define a macro to perform the intended operation. When overloading (or, rather, replacing), `#undef` the macro and define a new one. Works for either C or C++, although incredibly dangerous.

In C, overloading or replacing functions is not an option. Either you would have to use the preprocessor, as mentioned above, or actually edit the resulting binary to use your functions.

In C++, you could make a polymorphic class that uses virtual functions, overriding the definition that was previously there. This would be the easiest solution to override the operation of the library itself.

In either language, it would be extremely difficult to change the type of a variable or value of a constant without recompiling.

Comment: this is extremly dangerous. you may undef some critical macro the system or the platform has supllied.

Comment: The problem with macros are that if redefinition will only have effect at compile time only in the compilation unit where it's redefined. The library will still use the variant that was defined during library compilation.

Answer (score -2):

1. Global function pointer ?
2. Functor overload ?

#### Global function pointer

Let say your library defines a `doCoffee()` function this way:

```
void doCoffee_impl() { /* ... */ }
void (doCoffee*)(void) = doCoffee_impl;
```

Your library users can then replace the behaviour of doCoffee by reaffecting the global variable.

#### Functor overload

But, hey! you're coding C++. Why not use a virtual `operator()` ?

```
struct Brewer
{
    virtual operator()() { /* ... */ }
} brewer;
brewer *doCoffee = &brewer;
```

Your users may overload this:

```
struct UserBrewer : public Brewer
{
    virtual operator()() { /* ... */ }
} userBrewer;
doCoffee = &userBrewer;
```

Let to the reader: either declare variables static in the source header or define it extern and define the variable in a provided compilation unit.

Comment: Tell me exactly the advantage of your virtual function over regular function pointers? Extra indirection comes at a cost.

Comment: It's context dependant. the functor approach allow for a stateful function.